# Is it possible to place copies from illustrator transform above the original object?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transform

So when I use the transform tool in Illustrator and create several copies they always go behind the original element. Is it possible to place them above it?

[image]

**Here's a screenshot of the transform tool for clarification:**

[image]

Comment: How are you using the transform to make copies?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to do this in quick way.
But you always can use option **Reverse Order** in layer menu when all desired layers are selected.

[image: Reverse order]

Comment: Not the approach I expected, but this works just as well. Thank you!